# which is correct: she has complained ABOUT or AGAINST me to the principal

Tags: prepositions, difference

which is correct:

> she has complained ABOUT or AGAINST me to the principal

Comment: She has complained **about** me to the principal.

Comment: In the 19th century, **complained against** was widely used, but in modern english, **complained about** is correct. Note that, when used as a noun in a legal context, **complaint against** is the correct usage.

Comment: And in a formal situation (where a complaint is written down and transmitted to an authority), you would typically say you *filed a complaint against* somebody.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complain+about%2Ccomplain+against&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplain%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomplain%20against%3B%2Cc0) has a strong opinion on this one

Answer (score 1):

The "ABOUT" form would be by far the more common. So:

> She has complained **about** me to the principal.

However, you might occasionally see "against" used in older or legal documents. For example:

> She has **filed** a complaint against...

or

> She has **lodged** a complaint against...

But I reckon those forms would tend to be used when the complaint is directed at an organization, or against an individual other than the person speaking.